# Django Can't Find Template in App

Tags: django

So i'm trying to build a basic blog in Django (am currently using the latest version of Django) and i'm running into a really annoying problem.  When I try and set up my html templates, I keep on getting a templatedoesnotexisterror.

Here's the rub--if I set up my html templates in the root app of the project ("blogcode"), they run perfectly.  But then, once I start running another app ("articles") and then I set up a templates folder using articles/templates/articles/homepage.html, all of the sudden, it doesn't work.  I can't get django to look anywhere but in the root app directory to find and ultimately render templates.

In my settings.py file, i've the DIRS list set to 'templates'.  When I tried changing it to os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') I get the same "templatedoesnot exist" error.  Also, my app IS properly installed in the INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.

I've tried looking in other documentation, but the only hints I can find are really outdated.  On the views.py, if I chop off the articles/, and just leave it as 'homepage.html' django renders it from the root app just fine and ignores the template in the articles app, but if I try and get it to render from the articles app, I get the "templatedoesnotexist" error.  What's going on?

Here's my code:

**articles/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.startpage, name='startpage'),

]
```

**articles/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Article


def startpage(request):
    return render(request, 'articles/homepage.html')
```

**blogcode/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'articles.apps.ArticlesConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'horror_blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'horror_blog.wsgi.application'
```

Answer (score 5):

Try register the app that way, and put django apps above your owns

Instead of

```
'articles.apps.ArticlesConfig',
```

Try this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ''' django apps'''
    'articles'
]
```

this `'DIRS': ['templates']` should be `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],`

Comment: I don't know who or where you are, but you just fixed the problem and got my project moving forward again!! THANK YOU!!  I hate that f*****ing Django Tutorial.

Comment: Did you replace the whole INSTALLED_APPS block, or just add this at the beginning or end?

Comment: I added it actually. Any app that you add in your project, it should be in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: wow. fixed it. thanks